# PHP grouping single array

Tags: php

i want to convert single array to group array like with this:

```
group_1
     1,2,3,4
group_2
     5,6,7,8
```

from single array like with this:

```
$arr=array('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8');
```

each group must be have 4 andis. and i can not programing that.
i want to have this result:

```
array (
  'group_1'=>('1','2','3','4')
  'group_2'=>('5','6','7','8')
)
```

my simple and wrong code:

```
 <?php
 $singleArray= array(
    "arr_1",
    "arr_2",
    "arr_3",
    "arr_4",
    "arr_5",
    "arr_6",
    "arr_7",
    "arr_8",
 );
 $groups = array( 'group_1','group_2' );
 $groupArray = array();
 foreach( $singleArray as $key=>$arr ){
    if( $key != ['3','7'] ){
    $groupArray[][] = $arr;
    }
 }

 ?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`array_chunk()`](http://php.net/array_chunk) to split your array into two pieces, each containing 4 elements. Now use [`array_combine()`](http://php.net/array_combine) to create the result array using `$groups` as keys and the sliced array as values:

```
$result = array_combine($groups, array_chunk($singleArray, 4));
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/148802)